# match rows, create ranks and sum ranks by group in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a huge dataset with ~30,000 rows and ~17,000 columns, and a vector of `character` elements.

Here is a dummy set that recreates my dataset

```
### Example

df <- data.frame(Gene=paste0("gene", 1:60), replicate(60, runif(60, min=0, max=100)))
colnames(df) <- c("GeneName", paste0("TisA.", 1:20), paste0("TisB.", 1:20), paste0("TisC.", 1:20))

genes <- sample(df$GeneName, 5)

head(df)
#      GeneName    TisA.1    TisA.2    TisA.3   TisA.4
#1    gene1  1.987621 17.936562 18.145417 59.43023
#2    gene2 60.031713 73.822846 93.946769 72.27633
#3    gene3 44.833748 47.890719 77.100497 39.45719
#4    gene4 44.662776 26.285659 30.087606 49.50682
#5    gene5 63.770411  6.469006  3.797708 68.17532
```

I would need to match the elements in the vector for the dataframe, this is easily done with

```
 df.new <- df[df$GeneName %in% genes,]
```

Then, what I want is, for each one of the `genes`, to create rank values for each of the genes and then sum the ranks by `Tis` (A, B, C)

I can ordered values using for example for one `gene`

```
genes.ord <- sort(df.new[1,], decreasing = TRUE)
```

However, I am stuck from here, which will be the fastest way to assign ranks to the genes and sum those ranks by group, i.e., `TisA`, `TisB`, and `TisC`?

For clarification purposes each group has 20 samples `TisA.1, TisA.2, ..., TisA.20`

A desired output would be:

```
 GeneName   TisA TisB TisC
    gene4     24   32   10 ## these are random values to show sum of ranks for each of genes in the vector
    gene1     14   12   20 ## these are random values to show sum of ranks for each of genes in the vector
   gene40      4   92   12 ## these are random values to show sum of ranks for each of genes in the vector
    gene2     64    2   40 ## these are random values to show sum of ranks for each of genes in the vector
   gene15     84   32    9 ## these are random values to show sum of ranks for each of genes in the vector
```

P.S some values in my real dataset can be 0 and be repeated in different columns

Comment: What type of "group" are you talking about? Your genes are labelled 1-60 and you have 60 rows.

Comment: the "group" will be "TisA", "TisB", or "TisC", each of this have 20 elements e.g. "TisA.1", "TissA.2",...TisA.20"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Straightforward using the tidyverse

```
# your data. Including seed to make it reproducible
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Gene=paste0("gene", 1:60), replicate(60, runif(60, min=0, max=100)))
colnames(df) <- c("GeneName", paste0("TisA.", 1:20), paste0("TisB.", 1:20), paste0("TisC.", 1:20))

library(tidyverse)
as.tbl(df) %>% 
    gather(key, value, -GeneName) %>% 
    group_by(GeneName) %>% 
    mutate(Ranks = rank(value, ties.method = "first"))  %>% 
    separate(key, into = c("key1", "key2"), sep = "[.]") %>% 
    group_by(GeneName,key1) %>% 
    summarise(Sum=sum(Ranks)) %>% 
    spread(key1, Sum)
# A tibble: 60 x 4
# Groups:   GeneName [60]
GeneName  TisA  TisB  TisC
*   <fctr> <int> <int> <int>
1    gene1   698   620   512
2   gene10   525   653   652
3   gene11   631   598   601
4   gene12   487   679   664
5   gene13   688   579   563
6   gene14   674   581   575
7   gene15   618   647   565
8   gene16   696   552   582
9   gene17   656   560   614
10  gene18   543   649   638
```

Or try a baseR solution...somewhat complicated

```
df1 <- apply(df[-1], 1, rank, ties.method= "first")
df2 <- apply(df1, 2, function(x){
  aggregate(x, list(sapply(strsplit(colnames(df), "[.]"), "[", 1)[-1]), sum)
  })
df3 <- cbind.data.frame(df$GeneName, t(Reduce(cbind, lapply(df2, "[", 2))))
colnames(df3) <- c("GeneName",  "TisA", "TisB", "TisC")
head(df3[order(df3$GeneName),])
GeneName TisA TisB TisC
   gene1  698  620  512
  gene10  525  653  652
  gene11  631  598  601
  gene12  487  679  664
  gene13  688  579  563
  gene14  674  581  575
```

Comment: Thanks Jimbou, it would be a easier way if the colnames group info, i.e, "TisA.1", "TisA.2" are stored in a data.frame and the real columns in my dataset would be a combinations of letters and numbers?